# Parse array params in Express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have an API like the following:

```
curl https://apps.fundamerica.com/api/offerings \
-u XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: \
-X POST \
-d amount="5000000" \
-d description="A+really+big+deal." \
-d max_amount="5500000" \
-d min_amount="4500000" \
-d name="Big+Deal" \
-d entity[city]="New+York" \
-d entity[country]="US" \
-d entity[email]="john.johnson%40johnson.com" \
-d entity[name]="Johnson%2C+Johnson%2C+Johnson+%26+Johnson" \
-d entity[phone]="12025551212" \
-d entity[postal_code]="10005" \
-d entity[region]="NY" \
-d entity[street_address_1]="60+Wall+St." \
-d entity[tax_id_number]="999999999" \
-d entity[type]="company" \
-d entity[executive_name]="John+Johnson" \
-d entity[region_formed_in]="NY"
```

and I need to parse properly those array params in Express. Do you know how to parse them correctly?

Comment: You may find [`bodyparser` module](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make make Express able to work with POST requests you should use one of  third-party modules, [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) for example.

First, install it:

```
npm install body-parser
```

And here is how you can make it work:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/api/offerings', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Parsed');
});

app.listen(1337);
```

You will get the whole POST data as an object in your console.